# Datatable columnDefs width not working with initComplete: function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

i'm creating table with Datatable, but when I set width with columnDefs it's not working well. this is my code http://dpaste.com/2QAXCX1

but when i delete script below, it columnDefs works well.

```
// init 
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([1,2,3,4,5,7,8]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    },
    // .init
```

Thanks.
fird0s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` elements expand your columns.

To avoid that add `width: 100%`:

```
var select = $('<select style="width: 100%;"><option value=""></option></select>')
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsmcan/tszby4Lr/)

You may need to add more markup to the elements to make table looking nice.